# scale div and table with in a4 size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It needs to scale(fit) this table with in the A4 size div
for convert to pdf with jsPDF. can do either javascript or css

[image]

like below (with in the page)

[image]

Code

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
div[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
@media print {
  body, div[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
Test Page</p>
<div size="A4">
<br/>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the div size by css to fit it in a A4 size paper CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #FAFAFA;
font: 12pt "Tahoma";
}
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

.page {
width: 21cm;
min-height: 29.7cm;
padding: 2cm;
margin: 1cm auto;
border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
border-radius: 5px;
background: white;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.subpage {
padding: 1cm;
border: 5px red solid;
height: 237mm;
outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
}

@page {
size: A4;
margin: 0;
}
@media print {
.page {
    margin: 0;
    border: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    width: initial;
    min-height: initial;
    box-shadow: initial;
    background: initial;
    page-break-after: always;
    }
   }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="book">
   <div class="page">
      <div class="subpage">Page 1/2</div>    
   </div>
   <div class="page">
       <div class="subpage">Page 2/2</div>    
   </div>
  </div>
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/3/

Comment: it's still same, i want like second image

Comment: i had update in this program it still not scaling down, [http://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/5926/](http://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/5926/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `length` of your cell size and get the correct `font-size` for the table fit correctly with your page with `Jquery`.

```js
var width = $(".A4").width() / $("td").length; // width of one cell
var fontSize = 12; 
$("td").each(function(i,e){
  $(this).css({width:width,fontSize:fontSize})
})
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
div[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
@media print {
  body, div[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Test Page</p>
<div class="A4" size="A4">
<br/>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

For make this you can use inevitably whether:

1. Breaking word (See below with CSS only)
2. Or calculate the exact font size for fit exaclty what you want (see first snippet)

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}

.A4 table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;  
  }
.A4 table td {
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
div[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
@media print {
  body, div[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Test Page</p>
<div class="A4" size="A4">
<br/>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
  <td>tableda g  gg g ta</td>
  <td>tabledaghn g g ta</td>
  <td>table tgh g g g data</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tablehn  g  gdat gngha</td><td>tabledata</td><td>tableg g g data</td>
  <td>tabledata</td>
  <td>table g g g  data</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledg g  ata</td><td>tablg  gh edata</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2">tableda g  gg g ta</td>
  <td>table tgh g g g data</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledata</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tablehn  g  gdat gngha</td><td>tabledata</td><td>tableg g g data</td>
  <td>tabledata</td>
  <td>table g g g  data</td><td>tabledata</td>
  <td>tabledg g  ata</td><td>tablg  gh edata</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this is not a fixed columns, i want it dynamically scale the table or div fit with in the container

Comment: You can choose the size of your table and its position. Not fixed only